# excel vba copy selected data range from multiple sheets to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy selected data range from sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3 to a new workbook sheet1,sheet2 and sheet3, below codes just working fine copy for sheet1 and sheet2, but not sheet3; when comes to sheet3, it always copy the sheet1 data instead of sheet3; what is missing from my code?

(note:for all sheet 1 and 3 sheets i reference data range to copy from cell F1.)

Thank you.

```
Set Source1 = Range(Sheet12.Range("f1")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error GoTo 0

If Source1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Source1.Copy
With Dest.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


End With

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
Dest.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

' --------2------------------------

 Set dest2 = ActiveWorkbook

Set source2 = Sheet16.Range("a2:q1000")

source2.Copy

With dest2.Sheets(2)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With

'----------3--------

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
Dest.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate

 Set dest3 = ActiveWorkbook
Set source3 = Range(Sheet20.Range("f1")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 

source3.Copy

With dest3.Sheets(3)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Cells(1).Select
       Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With
'----------/3-------
```

Comment: `dest3.Sheets(3)` refers to the third created sheet. it does not necessarily refer to `Sheets("Sheet3")`. if you open a new workbook with one worksheet, and you rename the worksheet "Sheet3" then _Sheets(1)_ will refer to _Sheets("Sheet3")_ ... also, do not use `Select ... Selection ... Activate ... ActiveSheet` ... refer to any cell by full "path" `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Copy` ...  `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").PasteSpecial` ... and if you have multiple workbooks, then refer to workbook by name _workbook.sheet.range. ..._

Comment: ya, agreed my codes are messy, will look thru and clean up, thank you.

Comment: Hi, if i use proper path, the result still the same, no sheet3 data copied. 
 If i change the reference cell to data range, it work. 

eg.  Set source3 = Sheet20.Range("b2:r75") is working.

Not : Set source3 = Range(Sheet20.Range("f1")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

How can i do the data range reference based on cell value correctly?

Comment: have tried many other method, still not working, is there any other method to copy cell value reference to data range? no matter how i change the code, it only work when i put the exact range, ie. b2:r75, but this is not i want, because i have dynamic data range to select instead of fixed data range.

Comment: which sheet is Sheet20 ?

Comment: I have many sheets in my workbook, from sheet1 to sheet30, sheet20 is where I keep the data